# Slow, word-by-word terminal printing in Python?

Tags: python, unix, terminal, printf

I'm writing a Python app involving a database. For the hell of it, I'm including an easter egg. If the user decides to nuke his database, all this from a terminal, he'll be prompted to confirm with a simple (y/n). But if he types DLG2209TVX instead, the lines from that scene of WarGames will print. Doubt anybody will ever find it unless they look through my source, but that's okay.

The problem is that simply printing the lines plays the scene way too fast and really just ruins it. I implemented a timer between each character's lines to slow things down, and it's better, but it still seems unnatural. Is there a standardized way to slowly print each word or character out instead of doing it lines at a time? Or should I just start adding timers between words?

Comment: Have you tried `time.sleep()`? 
`sleep(seconds):Delay execution for a given number of seconds.  The argument may be
a floating point number for subsecond precision.`

Comment: They don't have to read your source code, they just have to come across this stackoverflow question! :-)

Comment: Related: [`curl -L cueup.com/jobs`](http://tech.cueup.com/blog/2013/03/06/how-our-terminal-friendly-jobs-page-works/) (demonstrates slow printing)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Standardized?  Not that I know of.  But try this:

```
import random
import sys
import time

def slowprint(s):
    for c in s + '\n':
        sys.stdout.write(c)
        sys.stdout.flush() # defeat buffering
        time.sleep(random.random() * 0.1)

slowprint('Hello, world.')
```

Adjust the `0.1` to change the maximum delay between characters, and add lengthy `time.sleep()`s between lines to add more dramatic effect.

Answer (score 1):

```
import sys
import time
for c in gettysburg_address:
  sys.stdout.write(c)
  sys.stdout.flush()
  # 110 baud:
  time.sleep( 8./110 )
  # 300 baud:
  #  time.sleep( 8./300 )
```

Comment: muchas gracias, works like charm

Answer (score 1):

You can also try [`curses.delay_output()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html#curses.delay_output):

```
In [48]: import curses

In [49]: for x in "foo bar":
    sys.stdout.write(x)     #prints each char with a delay of 100ms
    curses.delay_output(100)
   ....:     
foo bar
```

Comment: aha and that is what i meant by standardized. thank you